# Use a .db file with MS Chatbot

Tags: database, sqlite, azure, request, chatbot

Here is my situation : I'm developing a Chatbot on Microsoft azure platform using Node.js. For the moment the bot messages are hard-coded in .json files.
I want to improve it by using calls to a database.

I have a SQLite database file working fine (I used a browser for SQLite and made my requests). But the problem is :

How do can I use my .db file from my project ? Is this possible to somehow "read" the database file from my dialogs and then make my request to get what I need from my database ?

[image: Organisation of my project]

I know that you can call a database with the chatbot, but the issue here is that I only have the file and nothing deployed to call.

Example of what the result should give :

"Hey chatbot, tell me about Mona Lisa" 
This triggers the dialogs that will ask the database : "SELECT info FROM arts WHERE arts.title LIKE '%Mona Lisa%' "; 
And send the result in session.send(results).

Thanks !

Note : I'm just an intern in my company, the database file is the only thing they gave me and I have to find a solution with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution after some research :
First you need to install sqlite3 with npm for example, then use this at the beginning of your code :

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var path = require('path');
var db_path = path.resolve(__dirname, name_Of_Your_DB);
```

And then work on your file with the request you need :

```
var db = new sqlite3.Database(db_path, sqlite3.OPEN_READONLY,(err) => {
      if (err) {
        return console.error(err.message);
      }
      //console.log("Stuff that is processed only if no error happened.");
    });
var req = "YOUR REQUEST";
    db.get(req, [your_parameter],(err, row) => {
      if (err) {
        return console.error(err.message);
      }
    });

    db.close((err) => {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err.message);
      }
    });
```

The documentation about node.js and sqlite3 is quite complete :
http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/query/